# Pyrebase authentication does not return successful case

Tags: firebase, flask, flask-wtforms, pyrebase

Hello I am making a web app using flask and am trying to implement firebase authentication through pyrebase but am unable to get a successful login. I can't seem to get `auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)` to work.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
    successful = 'Login successful'
    form=LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = form.password.data
        email = form.email.data
        print(email)
        print(password)
        try:
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            print(user)
            return render_template('login.html', s=successful,form=form)
        except KeyError:
            return render_template('donation.html')
        except:
            return render_template('login.html', us=unsuccessful,form=form)
    return render_template('login.html',form=form)
```

It always end up going to this case `return render_template('login.html', us=unsuccessful,form=form)`

This is my class for form.

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
```

This is the login.html.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}

{% if s %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h2>{{s}}</h2>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if us %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <h2>{{us}}</h2>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<h1>Sign In</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{wtf.quick_form(form)}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I has my pyrebase/auth initializations in a a different file from my routes. I put

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()
```

along with the firebase configuration in the same file as my routes and I got a successful authentication.